# How to keep checkbox state while browsing between navigation bar items

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter, I have a bottom navigator bar and there are 4 different bottom navigator bar items in it. In the 4th menu item, I have a checkbox widget. While browsing in the navigation bar items I would like the checked or unchecked items situation remains. For example if I uncheck this widget I would like it to stay still "unchecked" while browsing in other navigation bar items. How can I do this? I tried to use key parameter of checkbox but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)
to keep state Alive while you browse between your items.Extend your state class with it and create an override method wannaKeepAlive and set it to true.Here is an example of a widget using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this but it did not work. The problem still continues.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to State management!
[Official guideline for state management from Flutter team](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

I would recommend to read everything starting from [introduction to state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).